# Doctrine select foreign-key value instead of object

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

### The issue

To best explain, their are 4 entities:

```
Person [id, address, :person_name_id]  
PersonName [id, text_value]  
Trait [id, :person_id, :traitname_id]  
TraitName [id, text_value]
```

The only way I am able to get the array result I want is to use php to loop through and update various parts.
I would really like a way to achieve this using doctrine/mysql?

I've tried selecting `'job_name.text_value as name'` and `'trait_name.text_value as name'` (or traitname), but this results in only a single trait being returned and the person name does not get placed inside the existing root element of the array.

### The data structure i'm striving for:

```
[
  id => 1,
  address => 'xyz lane',
  name => 'bob',
  traits => [
    [
      id => 1,
      name => 'eats bananas'
    ],
    [
      id => 2,
      name => 'likes fishing'
    ]
  ]
]
```

### The current data structure:

```
[
  id => 1,
  address => 'xyz lane',
  person_name => [
    id => 1,
    text_value => 'bob'
  ]
  traits => [
    [
      id => 1,
      trait_name => [
        Id => 1,
        text_value => 'eats bananas'
      ]
    ],
    [
      id => 2,
      trait_name => [
      person_name => [
        id => 2,
        text_value => 'likes fishing'
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

### Finally the doctrine query:

```
$q = $this->createQueryBuilder('person')
->select(
    'person',
    'person_name',
    'person_traits',
    'trait_name'
    )
->from('AppBundle:Person','person')
->innerJoin('person.name','person_name')
->leftJoin('person.traits','person_traits')
->leftJoin('person_traits.trait_name', 'trait_name')
->where('person.id = :id')
->setParameter('id', 1);  

return $q->getQuery()->getSingleResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Comment: Only thing that comes to my mind is indeed to `select ('person.name as personname)` etc. 
But be aware that every AS definition needs to be unique (e.g. name must not be there twice in your result).
And you probably need to build up your structure after you get all results in a single array, so I don't know if it really helps.